# Error while trying to pass a date value to a UDT from mule Database connector

Tags: mule, oracle-sqldeveloper, datetime-format, dataweave, mule4

I have a requirement where I need to invoke UDT type defined in stored Procedure on Oracle, from Mule flow. To attain this I am creating a JDBC array type like:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
  inParam: Db::createArray("Database_Config","ADDRESS_TAB",[ Db::createStruct("Database_Config","ADDRESS_TAB_TYPE",
     ["TESt-Mule",**("2015-07-04T21:01:01") as DateTime**,"WB"])
    ])
}
```

the oracle ADDRESS_TAB_TYPE is

```
ADDRESS_TAB TABLE OF ADDRESS_TAB_TYPE
Name                Null? Type          
------------------- ----- ------------- 
IADDRESS_NAME             VARCHAR2(240)   
IINACTIVE_DATE            DATE          
ISTATE                    VARCHAR2(150)
```

type of date defined on Oracle side is DATE

after invoking the flow I am getting below error:

```
    ERROR 2021-03-18 23:14:06,971 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [playground].oracle-db-loc-testFlow.CPU_INTENSIVE @4d9589a8] [processor: ; event: 876ad840-8811-11eb-a282-a483e7749b4e] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "org.mule.weave.v2.el.ExpressionFunctionCallException: Exception while executing createStruct("Database_Config","ADDRESS_TAB_TYPE",
         ["TESt-Mule",**("2015-07-04T21:01:01") as DateTime**,"WB"])
        ]) cause: An error occurred when trying to create JDBC Structure. Fail to convert to internal representation: 2015-07-04T21:01:01Z 
Trace:
  at callFunction (Unknown)
  at createStruct (line: -1, column: -1)
  at createArray (line: 5, column: 73)
  at main (line: 5, column: 12)
```

I am trying to pass this datevalue to oracle, Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used this transformation:
fun dateTimeFormat(inputDateTime) = inputDateTime as DateTime as String{format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"}

and it worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would the suggestion here help you out maybe ?

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXXV4/how-to-insert-the-date-value-into-oracle-database-using-mule-4

Comment: Links for references in answers are good but link only answers should be avoided  and could be flagged.